# Monitor connected to HDMI port does not work

Tags: vaio, sony, dockstation

I have installed Ubuntu on my old Sony VAIO. Works fine and is quick enough but external monitor via HDMI port does not work. External monitor via VGA port works fine and I can even change the picture between laptops own screen and external VGA monitor using Sonys function button. Definitely no cable, nor monitor, issue because my other Windows PC works fine with the same HDMI cable and same HDMI monitor, which also worked with this VAIO before I installed UBUNTU. Please note that the VAIO is now pure Linux machine, no Windows partition. Any idea what to do?

Comment: The problem is that external monitor HDMI connection does not work. Not on laptop itself and not through the docking station. External monitor with VGA works fine.

Comment: Definitely no cable, nor monitor, issue because my other Windows PC works fine with the same HDMI cable and same HDMI monitor, which also worked with this VAIO before I installed UBUNTU. Please note that the VAIO is now pure Linux machine, no Windows partition.

Comment: Good hint! That worked out when connecting the HDMI monitor directly to VAIO HDMI port. However, when using the docking station  in between, there was no help. Even if I gave power on/off to docking station or to the monitor. The VGA works via the docking station fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Monitor power off, unplug, plug back, power on

This works for the monitor directly connected by HDMI or Display Port to the computer.

It is important to completely unplug the monitor. Just powering off using the button on the monitor does not seem to work.

Hope this helps