# HDMI and Mini Displayport outputs not detecting external monitors on MSI GS65 running 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi, msi

The HDMI output is not detecting external monitors on my MSI GS65 running Ubuntu 18.04. I have the NVIDIA 390.77 driver installed, which works great since I am able to run games smoothly on Steam. I do not think the issue is with the NVIDIA drivers because the HDMI output issue seems to be related to motherboard drivers. Edit: Mini DisplayPort also does not work.

Update1: A reinstallation of the NVIDIA drivers did not work and turned out to be a nightmare. Upon reinstalling the NVIDIA drivers, the system kept in reverting to Intel drivers that could not be switched to the NVIDIA ones. A clean reinstallion of Ubuntu fixed it that issue but still no HDMI or mini DisplayPort function.

Update2: Looking at new posts with external monitors not detected there seems to be a general trend with Ubuntu 18.04 having issues with external monitors regardless of it being on MSI laptops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution which happened to be pretty simple. Basically power monitor off, unplug, plug back, and then power on. Thanks to user68186 from this thread [Monitor connected to HDMI port does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098236/monitor-connected-to-hdmi-port-does-not-work).

Edit: This is a side note but it is pretty amazing how many problems overlap and one has to search all pertinent threads to be resourceful. There was an inefficiency of how I used stacks and I think this might be a general problem. Constant moderation is perhaps always needed.

Comment: Update: I still have the issue if the laptop has been in hibernation or sleep (not sure which). But if left off, at least overnight, external monitors are detected. So it is definitely a hardware use issue with drivers (same charged capacitor?).

Comment: Ran into a different issue where the solution was found on: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1044461/linux/nvidia-410-73-extend-monitor-can-not-be-detected/

Comment: This solution not work for my GS65

Comment: Works for GF63 Thin 9RCK